# Google Cloud Storage Permission from Un-launched app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

What do you guys do when developing locally (using GoogleAppEngine SDK) and you need to use Google Cloud Storage?

Is there a way to grant permission to an "unlaunched" app?
Do you just open up the buckets permissions as a whole?
Is there a way to do it locally that will translate to deploying it with the real bucket?

I can get to and use Google Cloud SQL fine, but Google Cloud Storage has been a pain.

Comment: It would be helpful if you said specifically what aspect of Google Cloud Storage you are running into issues with. I'm able to save/read files from GCS with no problems locally.

Comment: I can't seem to read or write to the real GCS for the development app engine. Wanting to know if you can, and what permissions you need to grant your GCS bucket to be able to use the development app engine in reading and writing files.